# Are submatrices of an arbitrary complex unitary matrix diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, unitary-matrices

Consider a complex unitary matrix $U \in \mathbb{C}^{N\times N}$ and pick two diagonal and two off-diagonal elements from its $m$th and $n$th rows to construct a $2 \times 2$ submatrix:
\begin{equation}
M=
\begin{bmatrix}
U_{mm} & U_{mn}\\
U_{nm} & U_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
U_{mm} & U_{mn}\\
(U_{mn})^* & U_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

(Here I consider the Hermitian case $U_{nm} = (U_{mn})^*$.) Is $M$ always diagonalizable?

**Update**:

Conjecture: $M$ should be diagonalizable.
Because $U$ is unitary, the eigenvectors of $U$ should span a linear space of dimension $N$.
If there exists any $M$ not diagonalizable, the eigenvectors of that $M$ does not span a dimension $2$ space.

Brute force proof:
find the eigenvectors of this [sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBPcy.png) $2\times 2$ submatrix.
Its eigenvectors are also shown in the figure. ($a_{1,2}, b_{1,2} \in \mathbb{R}$, and $c \in \mathbb{C}$)

For the two eigenvectors to be identical, the following two equations need to be satisfied:
\begin{equation}
(a_1-b_1)^2 - (a_2-b_2)^2 + 4|c|^2 = 0 \text{ and } (a_1-b_1)(a_2-b_2) = 0.
\end{equation}
Clearly, both equations can be simultaneously satisfied.
When they are both satisfied, $M$ does not have two independent eigenvectors and therefore is not diagonalizable.

This result looks counter-intuitive.

Moreover, I started to think about this question when studying [this historic paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.73.58).
This paper is about a recursive way of building **any** $N\times N$ unitary matrix with optical experiments.
Its [equation 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuheR.png) shows that by applying in total $N-1$ different $2\times 2$ rotational matrices to a $(N-1)\times (N-1)$ unitary matrix, one can construct a $N\times N$ unitary matrix.
Performing this recursively, one can use $N(N-1)/2$ rotational matrices to construct a $N\times N$ unitary matrix starting from an identity matrix.

However, it seems that we just showed that not all unitary matrices $U$ can be constructed in this way...

Comment: What have you found in your efforts?  (I'm assuming you know that math.se is not a "do my work for me" service. So I ask, again, for your contribution: context, source of question?, work?).  Please read [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults&s=1|128.2670).

Comment: All those matrices are very likely to be diagonalizable, so this conjecture makes sense. What have you tried to do so far?

Comment: What do you mean by Hermitian case ?

Answer (score 6):

The answer is no. Let
$$\begin{pmatrix}{1\over 2} &{1\over \sqrt{2}} & {1\over 2}\\
-{1\over 2} &{1\over \sqrt{2}}& -{1\over 2}\\
-{1\over \sqrt{2}} & 0 &  {1\over \sqrt{2}}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The submatrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}
{1\over \sqrt{2}}& -{1\over 2}\\
 0 &  {1\over \sqrt{2}}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is not diagonalizable.